# Problem with reverse attributes in PonyORM model definitions

Tags: python, orm, ponyorm

I am getting an `inconsistent reverse attributes` exception from my PonyORM model definitions.  I have spent 90 minutes reading other SO issues and the docs but can't figure out how to resolve this.

code:

```py
from datetime import date, datetime
from pony import orm

db = orm.Database()

class Milestone(db.Entity):
    cat     = orm.Required(str)
    subcat  = orm.Required(str)
    orm.PrimaryKey(cat, subcat)

    planned = orm.Optional('DateSet', reverse='milestone')
    actual  = orm.Optional('DateSet', reverse='milestone')


class DateSet(db.Entity):
    start       = orm.Optional(date)
    end         = orm.Optional(date)
    workingdays = orm.Optional(int)
    created     = orm.Required(datetime, sql_default='CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
    milestone   = orm.Optional(Milestone)


db.bind(provider='sqlite', filename='local.db', create_db=True)
orm.set_sql_debug(True)
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)
```

The above can be executed directly to produce the error below.

exception:

```bash
pony.orm.core.ERDiagramError: Inconsistent reverse attributes Milestone.actual and DateSet.milestone
```

Is there an option *not* to have a reverse mapping?  I don't need it and I'd rather not have it.  In my case the `DateSet` entity will be used in many places (not just `Milestones`) so I'd actually prefer not to have that attribute on the entity at all, and just have a one-way relationship.

Put differently, imagine I have an entity `AnnotatedDateRange` which contains `start: date`, `end: date`, `note: str` -- I might use AnnotatedDateRange as follows:

```
Foo.period1: AnnotatedDateRange
Foo.period2: AnnotatedDateRange
Bar.duration: AnnotatedDateRange
Wibble.calendarhold: AnnotatedDateRange
```

So just because `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Wibble` all have attributes which reference instances of entity type `AnnotatedDateRange` does not mean that I want every instance of `AnnotatedDateRange` to have some mechanism to refer back to the referring entity.